# Series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}f_n$ converges almost everywhere for $f_n\in L^2$ with given condition

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $f_n\in L^2[0,1]$, and we have that for each $\epsilon>0$ there exists $N_0\ge1$ so that $\|\sup_{N>N_0}|\sum_{n=N_0}^Nf_n|\|_2<\epsilon$. Prove that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} f_n$ converges almost everywhere.

If we set $F_n=\sum_{k=1}^nf_k$ and $F=\limsup_nF_n$ and $G=\liminf_nF_n$. Let $A=\{x\in[0,1]:F(x)>G(x)\}$ and $A_k=\{x\in[0,1]:F(x)>2^{-k}+G(x)\}$. We want to show that $m(A)=0$. Note that $A=\cup_{k=1}^{\infty}A_k$ and $A_k\subset A_{k+1}$, so $\lim_{k\to\infty}m(A_k)=m(A)$. So how to show that $\lim_{k\to\infty}m(A_k)=0$? Thanks for any hint.

As mentioned in the comment below, we want to show that for each $\epsilon$ we have $m(A_k)\le\epsilon^24^k$. By the condition given, we have $\|\sup_{N>N_0}|F_N-F_{N_0-1}|\|_2<\epsilon$ which implies $m(\{x:\sup_{N>N_0}|F_N-F_{N_0-1}|>2^{-k}\})\le\epsilon^24^k$. Can we show that $A_k\subset\{x:\sup_{N>N_0}|F_N-F_{N_0-1}|>2^{-k}\}$ or $F(x)-G(x)<\sup_{N>N_0}|F_N-F_{N_0-1}|$?

Comment: The set where your supremum function is larger than $2^{-k} $ has measure less than $\epsilon^2 4^k $. Your $ A_k $ is a subset of that set. Varying epsilon shows that $ A_k$ has measure zero

Comment: @Bananach How can we get that the set where supremum function is larger than $2^{-k}$ has measure less than $\epsilon^24^k$? Also, if $G(x)$ is negative, $A_k$ will not be subset of this set.

Comment: First question: use $\|f\|\geq L (m(\{x: |f (x)|\geq L\}))^{1/2}$. Second question: rethink this. But you are right in that my original comment should say "Your A_{k-1} is a subset... that A_{k-1} has measure zero"

Comment: @Bananach For the first question, from the condition given we can only get that $m(\{x:\sup_{N>N_0}|F_N-F_{N_0-1}|\ge 2^{-k}\})\le\epsilon^24^k$. Can we show that $\sup_{N>N_0}|F_N-F_{N_0-1}|\ge F$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will not use (at least directly) the approach suggested in the comments. Define $s_n:= \sum_{i=1}^nf_i$ and $d_N:=\sup_{m,n\geqslant N}\left|s_m-s_n\right|$. Since $d_N\leqslant 2\sup_{i\geqslant N}\left|s_i-s_N\right|$, we have by assumption that $\lVert d_N\rVert_2\to 0$ as $N$ goes to infinity. Since $d_{N+1}\leqslant d_N$, we have $d_N\to 0$ almost everywhere (a subsequence convergences to $0$, and by monotonicity, the whole sequence converges to $0$), hence the sequence $\left(s_n(x)\right)_{n\geqslant 1}$ is Cauchy for almost every $x$.